# SQL script to find previous value, not necessarily previous row

Tags: sql, hana

is there a way in SQL to find a previous value, not necessarily in the previous row, within the same SELECT statement?

See picture below.  I'd like to add another column, ELAPSED, that calculates the time difference between TIMERSTART, but only when DEVICEID is the same, and I_TYPE is viewDisplayed. e.g. subtract 1 from 2, store difference in 3, store 0 in 4 because i_type is not viewDisplayed, subtract 2 from 5, store difference in 6, and so on.

It has to be a statement, I can't use a stored procedure in this case.

```
SELECT DEVICEID, I_TYPE, TIMERSTART,
 O AS ELAPSED -- CASE WHEN <CONDITION> THEN TIMEDIFF() ELSE 0 END AS ELAPSED
FROM CLIENT_USAGE
ORDER BY TIMERSTART ASC
```

I'm using SAP HANA DB, but it works pretty much like the latest version of MS-SQL.  So, if you know how to make it work in SQL, I can make it work in HANA.

[image]

Comment: Don't use images is SO, especially code: we can't copy the text. Please add your query again.

Comment: Also: tag your DBMS. Is it sql server? add the version, too - it can be done easily if you have 2012+

Answer (score 1):

You can make a subquery to find the last time entered previous to the row in question.

```
select deviceid, i_type, timerstart, (timerstart - timerlast) as elapsed.
from CLIENT_USAGE CU
join ( select top 1 timerstart as timerlast
       from CLIENT_USAGE C 
       where (C.i_type = CU.i_type) and 
         (C.deviceid = CU.deviceid) and (C.timerstart < CU.timerstart)
       order by C.timerstart desc 
     ) as temp1
on temp1.i_type = CU.i_type
order by timerstart asc
```

This is a rough sketch of what the sql should look like I do not know what your primary key is on this table if it is i_type or i_type and deviceid. But this should help with how to atleast calculate the field. I do not think it would be necessary to store the value unless this table is very large or the hardware being used is very slow. It can be calculated rather easily each time this query is run.

Comment: Sorry did not see that this was hana before I wrote my response.

Answer (score 0):

SAP HANA supports window functions:

```
select DEVICEID,
       TIMERSTART, 
       lag(TIMERSTART) over (partition by DEVICEID order by TIMERSTART) as previous_start
from CLIENT_USAGE
```

Then you can wrap this in parentheses and manipulate the data to your hearts' content

Comment: Thanks JohnHC, but Lag() looks at the previous row, in my case that's not necessarily where the previous value is stored.  The condition i_type = 'viewDisplayed' must be met.  Please look at the pic, and my description.

Comment: @user1375218 So take this, and apply the additional things you want it to do. This is not a code writing service.